# Литовский/боярсский

Tags: орфография

Почему от *Литовск* мы пишем *литовский*, но от *Боярский* — *боярсский*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правильно:**

Литва — **литов/ск/ий**, суффикс СК,

Литовск — **литовск/ий**, полное наложение суффикса СК на основу,

бояре — **бояр/ск/ий**, суффикс СК,

Боярский — **боярс/ск/ий,** усечение основы на К и суффикс СК; такая модель используется, чтобы **различить** два относительных прилагательных (боярский и боярсский).

Сравнить: ***Боярсские** песни* (**название** сборника песен, прописная буква).

**ПРАВИЛО**

Варианты написания относительных прилагательных  для существительных **с основой на *СК***

1. **ОДНА БУКВА С**

Одна буква С в относительном прилагательном пишется **при полном наложении суффикса *СК*** на основу существительного.
Полное наложение суффикса СК на основу существительного делается для того, чтобы избежать  стечения  согласных и преимущественно в  **русских** названиях: ***Курск – курский, Томск – томский.***

(2) **ДВЕ БУКВЫ СС**

Две буквы СС в относительном прилагательном пишутся **при усечении** основы существительного **перед суффиксом *СК***.

Здесь происходит усечение буквы К в основе исходного существительного перед суффиксом СК (обычно в **иноязычных** названиях) и удвоение СС на стыке усеченной основы на С и суффикса СК: ***дамаск – дамасский, этруск – этрусский.***

Comment: Только я вот не думаю, что надо писать с большой буквы *боярсские песни*.

Comment: Думала об этом. С одной стороны, пушкинские стихи, это всем понятно. А вот боярсские песни могут и не понять. Можно считать, что это условное название  сборника его песен. Как вариант.

Comment: В ПАС написано, что с суффиксом *-ск*, как правило, с малой буквы пишем. Это же не *Бояровы песни*, то бишь суффикс *-ов*.

Comment: Это да, поэтому я добавила название сборника.